# Ubuntu will crash during light and heavy usage

Tags: crash

I am looking to pin point a run time bug. I believe the problem lies in the installation but I would like to verify if this issue is with the installation before I do a reinstall.

Problem: When using Ubuntu it will sometimes crash. The crash causes the keyboard, mouse ,and ports to lose all functionality. This used to be a dual booted computer running windows and Ubuntu. I updated the kernel and this did not correct the issue.
Hardware as been confirmed with 99% certainty not be the problem.

Comment: I was looking into creating a bash script to log events to see if I could better pin point the problem. I did not find anything using this but that may be due to lack of knowledge on my part. https://ackcent.com/basics-linux-events-logging/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Overheating is most likely caused by dust. Power down your system. Unblock your fans and vents, clean out the dust. Ensure air circulation. Dust that coats heat exchangers and chips is a good insulator,  and bad for cooling. Don't disassemble your computer until you have downloaded the manufacturer's  manual, and researched how-to-clean. Make this information available for when your computer isn't (paper, other computer) **Don't use water.**

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Comment: Thanks for the direction I will look into it.